# Google Map appears in one template but not other though both have same code

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript

I am using two different layouts for one single page with two different templates. Both contains Google Map. The switching takes place according to the option selected by the user through parent constructor in block file.

Now the code I am using for both the templates is similar in all respects : from div structure to Javascript used for the Map. Only difference is a slight height, width of "map_canvas" div that I change in the other template.

I cant understand why the map doesnot load in that other template; while it works fine in the first one and it shows only grey area!!Following are the file contents:

Template file1 (Google Map works fine here):

```
<div id="maps">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
<div id="panel"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var state_or_stubVar = document.getElementById('state_or_stub');
    var zipcodeVar       = document.getElementById('zipcode');
    var allowFlag        = 0;

    function checkForm() 
    { 
         if(state_or_stubVar.value!=''){ allowFlag = 1; }
         else if(zipcodeVar.value!=''){ allowFlag = 1; }    

         if(allowFlag == 1){ return true; }
         alert('Enter Your State Or Postcode');
         return false;
    }

    var estimateDirectionLabel = '<?php echo $this->__('Calculating the estimated'); ?>';
    var gmapUrl = '<?php echo $this->getGoogleApiUrl(); ?>';
    var apiSensor = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('igex/storelocator_options/apisensor'); ?>;
    var stores = <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($this->getStores()->toArray()); ?>;
        var mediaUrl = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) ?>';
    var pathMarker = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) ?>';
    var defaultMarker = '<?php echo $this->getDefaultMarker(); ?>';
    var directionEnable = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('igex/storelocator_options/direction'); ?>;
        window.onload = loadScript;

</script>
```

Template file2 (Map doesnot show contains only grey area):

```
<div id="maps">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px;width:880px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="panel"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var state_or_stubVar = document.getElementById('state_or_stub');
    var zipcodeVar       = document.getElementById('zipcode');
    var allowFlag        = 0;

    function checkForm() 
    { 
         if(state_or_stubVar.value!=''){ allowFlag = 1; }
         else if(zipcodeVar.value!=''){ allowFlag = 1; }    

         if(allowFlag == 1){ return true; }
         alert('Enter Your State Or Postcode');
         return false;
    }

    var estimateDirectionLabel = '<?php echo $this->__('Calculating the estimated'); ?>';
    var gmapUrl = '<?php echo $this->getGoogleApiUrl(); ?>';
    var apiSensor = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('igex/storelocator_options/apisensor'); ?>;
    var stores = <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($this->getStores()->toArray()); ?>;
        var mediaUrl = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) ?>';
    var pathMarker = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) ?>';
    var defaultMarker = '<?php echo $this->getDefaultMarker(); ?>';
    var directionEnable = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('igex/storelocator_options/direction'); ?>;
        window.onload = loadScript;

</script>
```

CSS (common in both):

```
#map_canvas{
    width : 53%;
    height : 514px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#panel{
    float:left;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

Is it some magento error I am making or Some problem related to maps?? Any help would be appreciated. I tried following, nothing works:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860224/google-map-not-displaying-in-magento

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349476/map-isnt-showing-on-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-when-nested-in-a-div-tag

**EDIT:**
Chrome shows error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'observe' of null  in storelocator.js:101

Now storelocator.js code:

```
var markerVisitor = true;
function initialize(){
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOption = {zoom: 17, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, disableDefaultUI : true , zoomControl : true};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOption);
    direction = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map                 : map,
        panel               : document.getElementById('panel'),
        suppressMarkers     : true
    });
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("address"));
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', autocompleteCallback);

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    initGeoloc();
    initStores();
}

function getItineraire(lat, lng ){
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    if(markerVisitor){
    var origin = markerVisitor.getPosition();
    var request = {
        origin      : origin,
        destination : destination,
        travelMode  : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    }
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            direction.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
    }

}

function getMyLatLng(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        }, erreurPosition);
        return latlng;
    }
}

function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = gmapUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function initGeoloc(){
    if(apiSensor){
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            survId = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(maPosition,erreurPosition);
        }
    }
}

function maPosition(position) {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    markerPosition(latlng);
}

function erreurPosition(error) {
    var info = "Erreur lors de la géolocalisation : ";
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            info += "Timeout !";
            break;
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            info += "Vous n’avez pas donné la permission";
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            info += "La position n’a pu être déterminée";
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            info += "Erreur inconnue";
            break;
    }
}

function initStores(){
    markers = new Array();
    for(i=0; i< stores.items.length; i++){
        var latLng =  new google.maps.LatLng(stores.items[i].lat, stores.items[i].long);
        bounds.extend(latLng);
        if(stores.items[i].marker){
            var imgMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage(pathMarker+stores.items[i].marker);
        }else{
            if(defaultMarker){
                var imgMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage(pathMarker+defaultMarker);
            }else{
                var imgMarker = '';
            }
        }
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng, icon: imgMarker,map: map, store: stores.items[i]});
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', openWindowInfo);
        $('store'+stores.items[i].entity_id).observe('click', openWindowInfo.bind(markers[i]));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.panToBounds(bounds);
}


function openWindowInfo(){

    if(!this.store.image){
        this.store.image = defaultImage;
    }

    var content =   '<div class="store-info"><div class="store-image-div-infoWindow"><img src="'+this.store.image +'" alt="'+this.store.name+'"class="store-image-infoWindow"/></div><div class="store-name-infoWindow"><h3>' + this.store.name + '</h3>'
     + this.store.address + '<br>'
     + this.store.zipcode+' '+ this.store.city +' <br>'+ this.store.country_id + '<br>';


    if(this.store.phone){
        content += 'Phone : '+ this.store.phone + '<br>'
    }

    if(this.store.fax){
        content += 'Fax : '+  this.store.fax + '<br>'
    }
    content += "</div>";
    if(this.store.description){
        content += '<div class="store-description">'+ this.store.description+'</div>';
    }

    if(markerVisitor && directionEnable){
        content += '<span onclick="getItineraire('+this.store.lat+','+ this.store.long+')" class="span-geoloc">'+estimateDirectionLabel+'</span></div></div>';
    }

    infoWindow.setContent(content);
    infoWindow.open(map,this); 
}

function autocompleteCallback(){
    var place = this.getPlace();
    position = place.geometry.location;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.lat(), position.lng());
    markerPosition(latLng);
}

function markerPosition(latlng){
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    if(markerVisitor){
        markerVisitor.setPosition(latlng);
    }else{
        markerVisitor = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Vous êtes ici"
        });
    }
    map.panTo(latlng);
    map.setZoom(12);
}
```

Comment: Any js errors? Check the generated sources and see if they are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was related to javascript code that loaded all the markers which were displayed by default when the map was loaded for the first time.

This javascript code was lying somewhere near the the  tag that loaded the storename and above data which i missed to place in the **Template file2**.

Hence, after placing below line of code, everything works fine now:

```
<td style="cursor: pointer;" id="store<?php echo $store->getId() ?>"><?php echo $store->getName()?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('store'+stores.items[i].entity_id).observe('click', openWindowInfo.bind(markers[i]));
```

Throws an error, therefore the JS execution is aborted.

With a big thanks to @Marius :)